# Two dimensional parameter in Pyomo based on an initialized set

Tags: optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I have a 2-dimensional list as follows:

```
s = [
[0,0,9,6,8,1,6,2,3,9],
[0,0,0,3,1,1,2,5,7,8],
[3,10,0,2,6,4,0,4,8,3],
[7,10,10,0,9,0,2,3,10,7],
[1,10,8,9,0,9,6,6,8,8], 
[1,1,9,8,5,0,5,7,10,0],
[3,2,2,6,7,1,0,6,0,6],
[7,1,0,5,5,7,5,0,9,6],
[10,5,7,3,0,10,1,4,0,7],
[10,4,6,0,9,1,3,10,6,0]
]
```

Now, I would like to convert this list as a `Pyomo` parameter or if it is possible to use this list directly as a parameter in an equation as:

```
start[i] + p[i] + s[i,j] >= start[j]    for all i,j in J: i < j
```

What I have tried is defining my list and then adding a parameter as:

```
m.PAIRS_1 = Set(initialize = m.J * m.J, dimen=2, filter=lambda m, j, k : j < k)
m.setup   = Param(initialize = m.PAIRS_1, default = s)
```

but when I run the model, I have the following error:

```
KeyError: "Cannot treat the scalar component 'setup' as an indexed component"
```

I am wondering if, how can I fix that?

P.S: my main function to run the optimization model is as follows:

```
def schedule_machines(A, B):

  # create model
  m = ConcreteModel()

  # index set to simplify notation
  m.J       = Set(initialize=JOBS.keys())
  m.PAIRS_1 = Set(initialize = m.J * m.J, dimen=2, filter=lambda m, j, k : j < k)

  def s_initializer(m, i, j):
    return s[i][j]
  m.setup = Param(m.J, m.J, initialize=s_initializer)

  # decision variables
   ....

  # for binary assignment
  ...

  # optimization model
  ...

  # SolverFactory()
  ...

  return SCHEDULE

SCHEDULE = schedule_machines(A,B)
```

and all of the data are defined somewhere outside of the main function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this.  I'm making the assumption that `s` is always a square matrix (or there would be issues with your `start` variable).

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

s = [
[0,0,9,6,8,1,6,2,3,9],
[0,0,0,3,1,1,2,5,7,8],
[3,10,0,2,6,4,0,4,8,3],
[7,10,10,0,9,0,2,3,10,7],
[1,10,8,9,0,9,6,6,8,8], 
[1,1,9,8,5,0,5,7,10,0],
[3,2,2,6,7,1,0,6,0,6],
[7,1,0,5,5,7,5,0,9,6],
[10,5,7,3,0,10,1,4,0,7],
[10,4,6,0,9,1,3,10,6,0]
]

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.I = pyo.Set(initialize=range(len(s)))

m.IJ_subset = pyo.Set(within=m.I * m.I, 
    initialize=[(i, j) for i in m.I for j in m.I if i < j])

def s_initializer(m, i, j):
    return s[i][j]
m.setup = pyo.Param(m.I, m.I, initialize=s_initializer)

m.p = pyo.Param(m.I, initialize = 1.5)

m.start = pyo.Var(m.I, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def start_constraint(m, i, j):
    return m.start[i] + m.p[i] >= m.start[j]
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(m.IJ_subset, rule=start_constraint)

m.pprint()
```

Comment: Dear @AirSquid, thanks for your answer. When I run the function you mentioned inside my main function, it makes a throw as `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.  I just updated my question for clarification. Pleaes, take a look at that.

Comment: @A.Omidi I'm guessing that whatever you have in the `JOBS` dictionary doesn't have integers for keys and when you are initializing `m.J` with `JOBS.keys()` you are getting strings.  Inspect that dictionary and/or comment out the parts that error and inspect the set with `m.J.pprint()`

Comment: Dear @AirSquid, you are right. I have a dictionary to define the jobs specifications and those keys is a strings. What I cannot understand is the relation between the element inside a list as a parameter and dictionary keys! Actually, in other packages like CPLEX or CP-optimizer, it is convenient to use a list as a parameter inside the equation. But it seems in the Pyomo it is not easy.

Comment: Dear @AirSquid, would you pleaes see this [MRE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1X0GfE-OH1us7F8Y02OsE892f_nq7frjG?usp=sharing)?

Comment: @A.Omidi I don't understand your follow-up question.  I don't know what it means to "use a list as a parameter".  Parameters are just key-value pairings...  like a dictionary...there is a value for all members of the declared index set.

Comment: Dear @AirSquid, sorry if my comments were somewhat wordy. What you explained is actually what I want to say. 

Comment: I have some points. 1) in your model you define s, but you don't use that in your constraint. Do you miss that or having other reasons? 2) do you see the MRE?